# How to merge cells programmatically in a Google document table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

So I see that you can merge cells so that they span more than one column in a **document** table by selecting two or more cells and choosing "merge" from the document menu.

My question is how do you do this programmatically? For instance, if you

myTable.getChild(0).asTableRow().getCell(1).merge()

it just merges cell(1) with cell(0) and all subsequent cells move one column to the left rather than spanning the merged cell across two columns.

Any help here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation for your question:

```
merge()

Merges the element with the preceding sibling of the same type.

Only elements of the same ElementType may be merged. Any child elements contained in the current element are moved to the preceding sibling element.

The current element is removed from the document.
```

Here is the [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#merge()) for more reference.

Comment: Thank you, but I already read the documentation. It doesn't really address my question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google docs still don't offer this feature programmatically. Someone already asked this question back in 2013 and received what seems to be some [helpful workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596503/can-you-set-rowspan-colspan-through-apps-script-in-google-document/25933344#25933344).

Currently the documentation provides a single method for merging adjacent cells content into 1 cell, but don't maintain the original width of the 2 original cells.

Another workaround that might be relevant for this issue, is to create the table in Google spreadsheet and import it into the document. Google spreadsheets can provide a lot of freedom in styling your "table". [This](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/embed-google-spreadsheet-in-google-document) might be a good place to start.

Comment: This is for Google Sheets, not Google Documents.

Comment: Thanks @user1063287 for pointing this out. I updated the comment to be more relevant to the question asked.